# access different layout on activity apart from Main layout

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, layout, xamarin.android

I have a layout view "PopulatinData.axml" having one control what i am trying is to access layout in my activity class but only "main" layout is accessed in every activity.

**Want to DO**
`this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.XXXXXX)` //wnat to access PopulatingData layout

**PopulatingData.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="PopulateData">
    <TextView
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtpopulate" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know what's the exact way to access the layout aparft from main???

Comment: Use Layout Inflator.

Comment: @TarunVarshney can you please let me know the syntax even i can see this solution in setcontentview..but dont know how to access layout using this

Comment: Are you using Xamarin?

Comment: yes @TarunVarshney

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this. I am not very sure in Xamarin.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
 var layout = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XXXXXXX, layoutImages) as LinearLayout;
```

and for finding view-

```
this.yourview= layout.FindViewById<Button>(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and see if it solves your issue:

```
namespace FirstAndroidApp  
{

    [Activity(Label = "Activity1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Results);
        }
    }
}
```